# How do I display from seconds Days HH:MM:SS for a 9 hour day?

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS I found this code on here that I am using and it works great when I calculate a 24 hour day. I tried changing seconds to 32400 to calculate from seconds how many days for a 9 hour work day.

The problem is It will calculate the days but the remaining HH:MM:SS that show up are the same that I would see for a 24 hour calculation. It isn't giving me the correct #. For example if 26 hours I should see 1 day 2 hours for 24 hour and for a 9 hour I should see 2 days 8 hours. Instead I see 2 days 2 hours.....

Any ideas how I can modify this calculation to display correctly for remaining time after 9 hour days is calculated?

```
=IIF(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value < 86400, 
    Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), 
    Floor(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value / 86400) & " days, " & Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value < 32400, Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), Floor(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value / 32400) & " days, " &      Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!LoggedInTime.Value - (Floor(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value / 32400) *32400), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: thank you  I also added a sum - 
    =IIF(sum(Fields!ActivityTime.Value) < 32400, Format(DateAdd("s", sum(Fields!ActivityTime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), Floor(sum(Fields!ActivityTime.Value)/ 32400) & " days, " &      Format(DateAdd("s", sum(Fields!ActivityTime.Value) - (Floor(sum(Fields!ActivityTime.Value) / 32400) *32400), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"))

Comment: I have grouping of Supervisor/ MONTHYR/  Agent   so when I created my query I joined agent logged in data etc. to Activity Data - the logged in data is pre-aggregated and shows up repeating for each activity Agent has.  This is why I am using sum(Max(Field))  so that I only get one instance and my sum isn't duplicating values.  My activities on the other hand I do need to sum (so easier formula)   This is why I am showing scope as well of "AgentIDName" - I am calculating subtotals and totals also.    I am new to SSRS so I appreciate the help.

Comment: This ended up working for my situation:     
=IIF(sum(max(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "AgentIDName")) < 32400, 
    Format(DateAdd("s", sum(max(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "AgentIDName")), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), 
    Floor(sum(max(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "AgentIDName")) / 32400) & " days, " & Format(DateAdd("s", sum(max(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "AgentIDName"))-(Floor(sum(max(Fields!LoggedInTime.Value, "AgentIDName")) / 32400)*32400), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"))